# Magento import now keeps saying "File was not uploaded"

Tags: magento

Just took an import in Import/Export successfully, but a few things were off.

I dropped the database, created it again, then imported the backup from before the import. All data is there and clean just like it was.

I made the corrections to the import, now it doesn't upload. It says "File was not uploaded"

Nothing has changed. I renamed the import file, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded the old file, it works, uploads fine.

The problem must be in the new CSV, it must have errors and I'll have to start over with it and make sure it's clean.